# Issues with encoding with ElementTree module using XML and Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, encoding, elementtree

I am importing an xml file using ElementTree. I am attempting to append to this table element with the same row/cell format as below.

```
<Table>
   <Column/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">[u:1]</Data></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">0042</Data></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">59998</Data></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">6024</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
</Table>
```

Here is the pandas dataframe I am attempting to convert to xml

```
      COLA  COLB          COLC         COLD
0    [u:1]  0042  59997.843921  6023.868333
1    [u:1]  0043  62095.778828  6843.852777
2    [u:1]  0044  46923.763121      5073.63
3    [u:1]  0056  29162.183772  3176.141666
4    [u:1]  0076  75497.757104     6.804722
..     ...   ...           ...          ...
140  [u:1]  4083  12377.958868   208.096388
141  [u:1]  4085  15958.484981   195.759166
142  [u:1]  4086   8487.368626   325.531666
143  [u:1]  4087   5111.397846   157.406388
144  [u:1]  4089   8734.922832   270.993888
```

Here is the code I am using for converting the dataframe into XML.

```
def SubElementWithText(parent, tag, COLA, COLB, COLC, COLD):
    attrib = {}
    xmlInsert = '''
    <{tag}>
        <Cell><Data>{COLA}</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>{COLB}</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>{COLC}</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>{COLD}</Data></Cell>
    </{tag}>
    '''.format(tag="Row", COLA=COLA, COLB=COLB, COLC=COLC, COLD=COLD)

    #element = parent.makeelement(tag, attrib)
    element = ET.SubElement(parent, tag, attrib)
    parent.append(element)
    element.text = xmlInsert
    return element

templateXML = r"c:/users/USERNAME/desktop/hourOdomMeter_T_BASE.xml"
outputXML = r"c:/users/USERNAME/desktop/output.xml"

tree = ET.parse(templateXML)
root = tree.getroot()

tableElement = './/{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Table'
tableFind = root.find(tableElement)

for index, row in dfMerged.iterrows():
    SubElementWithText(tableFind, 'Row', row['COLA'], row['COLB'], row['COLC'], row['COLD'])

with open(outputXML, 'wb') as f:
    tree.write(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

I end up with this result below. The text is encoded and can't for the life of me get this squared away. Yes I am aware the new rows are nested one level too deep, will address this later. Not sure where the "ns0" namespace came from, ElementTree must assign this upon write().

```
  <ns0:Table>
     <ns0:Column/>
     <ns0:Row ns0:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <ns0:Cell><ns0:Data ns0:Type="String">[u:1]</ns0:Data></ns0:Cell>
        <ns0:Cell><ns0:Data ns0:Type="String">0042</ns0:Data></ns0:Cell>
        <ns0:Cell><ns0:Data ns0:Type="String">59998</ns0:Data></ns0:Cell>
        <ns0:Cell><ns0:Data ns0:Type="String">6024</ns0:Data></ns0:Cell>
     </ns0:Row>
    <Row>
      &lt;Row&gt;
          &lt;Cell&gt;&lt;Data&gt;[u:1]&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;
          &lt;Cell&gt;&lt;Data&gt;0042&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;
          &lt;Cell&gt;&lt;Data&gt;59997.843921&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;
          &lt;Cell&gt;&lt;Data&gt;6023.868333&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;
      &lt;/Row&gt;
      </Row><Row>
      &lt;Row&gt;
          &lt;Cell&gt;&lt;Data&gt;[u:1]&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;
          &lt;Cell&gt;&lt;Data&gt;0042&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;
          &lt;Cell&gt;&lt;Data&gt;59997.843921&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;
          &lt;Cell&gt;&lt;Data&gt;6023.868333&lt;/Data&gt;&lt;/Cell&gt;
      &lt;/Row&gt;
      </Row>
      ...
  <ns0:Table>
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: `element.text = xmlInsert` this is setting the element text (string) not creating an Element structure inside, that's why reserved characters like `<>` are html encoded. You should create the new sub-tree to append or try parsing the XML string and then append.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach to generating the xml - it's a little hacky, but does work. I would also use lxml instead of ElementTree, because of its superior xpath support.

```
from lxml import etree

tmpl = """<Table>`
   <Column/>   
</Table>"""

doc = etree.XML(tmpl)

frag = """<rows xmlns:ss="whatever" ss:AutoFitHeight="0">"""

for row in df.iterrows():
    frag += f"""
    <Row>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">{row[1].values[0]}</Data></Cell>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">{row[1].values[1]}</Data></Cell>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">{row[1].values[2]}</Data></Cell>
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">{row[1].values[3]}</Data></Cell>
       </Row>
       """
frag += """</rows>"""
elem = etree.fromstring(frag)
destination = doc.xpath('//Column')[0]

destination.addnext(elem)

print(etree.tostring(doc, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
```

The output should more or less what I think you're looking for. Obviously, you can tweak it to fit your needs.